# How to achieve accordion functionality with load more option?

Tags: jquery, html, css, magento

I want to display categories as accordion with load more functionality.
First time, I want to display only 3-4 categories, want to displaying remaining categories after click on load more link. it should be load less if click again on link.

For Ref. please see screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PokeydRXWebHJabmdXbFVtY2M/view

I am using below code :

```
    <div class="cat-dropdown" style="margin:25px 0; width:100%; float:left; clear:both">
        <?php
        $parentCatId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(); 
        $root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCatId);
        $subCat = explode(',',$root->getChildren()); 

        $collection  = $root
                     ->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                     ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in", $subCat) );
        ?>
<div class="products-grid first odd brand_list1">
                <?php foreach($collection as $catname){ 
                    $qty = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catname->getId())->getProductCount();?>
                           <div class="selected item<?php if (($i - 1) % $_columnCount == 0): ?> first<?php elseif ($i % $_columnCount == 0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                                <div class="cat-custom-img">
                                <h2 class="lavel-1"><a href="<?php echo $catname->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $catname->getName(); ?></a></h2>
                               <?php if($catname['sliderimage']) {  ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$catname['sliderimage']; ?>" alt= "" >
                               <?php } ?>
                               </div>
          <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catname->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0){ ?>
                                    <div class="catlist-toggle">
                                        <div class="catlist-toggle-inner">
                                        <ul class="second_level_cat myList">
                                            <?php $limit=1; ?>
                                             <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){ ?>
                                                    <li class="hide">
                                                        <h2><a href="<?php echo $_subcategory->getUrl(); ?>">
                                                            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName(); ?>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </h2>
                                                        <?php $_subcategory1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                                                        <?php $_subsubcategories1 = $_subcategory1->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                                        <?php if (count($_subsubcategories1) > 0){ ?>   
                                                            <ul class="third_level_cat myList">
                                                                 <?php foreach($_subsubcategories1 as $_subsubcategory){ ?>
                                                                 <li class="hide">
                                                                    <h2><a href="<?php echo $_subsubcategory->getUrl(); ?>" >
                                                                        <?php echo $_subsubcategory->getName(); ?>
                                                                    </a></h2>
                                                                    <?php $_subcategory2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subsubcategory->getId()) ?>
                                                                    <?php $_subsubcategories2 = $_subcategory2->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                                                    <?php if (count($_subsubcategories2) > 0){ ?>   
                                                                        <ul class="fourth_level_cat myList">
                                                                             <?php foreach($_subsubcategories2 as $_subsubcategory2){ ?>
                                                                             <li class="hide">
                                                                                <h2><a href="<?php echo $_subsubcategory2->getUrl(); ?>" >
                                                                                    <?php echo $_subsubcategory2->getName(); ?>
                                                                                </a></h2>
                                                                             </li>
                                                                            <?php }  ?>
                                                                        </ul>
                                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                                 </li>
                                                                <?php }  ?>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <?php $limit++; ?>
                                                    <?php // if($limit == 3){break;} ?>

                                             <?php } ?>
                                        <li class=""><div class="load-more">Load more</div></li>

                                        </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
                           </div>
                <?php   } ?>
            </div>
    </div>




<script>
    jQuery('.cat-dropdown').navAccordion({
     expandButtonText : "+", 
      collapseButtonText: "-", 
      selectedExpand: "true",  
      selectedClass: "selected",
      buttonPosition: "right",  
      headersOnly: false,  
      headersOnlyCheck: false,
      delayLink: false,  
      delayAmount: null 
    });
    </script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".load-more").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.selected').find('.catlist-toggle').toggleClass('expand');    
   });
   jQuery(".accordion-btn").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('.selected').find('.catlist-toggle').addClass('expand');   
   }); 
});

</script>



<style>
.selected.item{width: 23%;float: left;margin: 0 10px 55px 10px;}
.catlist-toggle{position: relative; }
.catlist-toggle.expand{height:auto;overflow:initial;}
.catlist-toggle.expand .catlist-toggle-inner ul{height:auto;overflow:initial;}
.catlist-toggle .catlist-toggle-inner{position: relative;  width: 100%;    top:0;    left: 0; background:#fff; z-index:9999;}
.catlist-toggle .catlist-toggle-inner ul{ z-index:9999; height: 220px;overflow:hidden; width:100%;}
.catlist-toggle .load-more{position: absolute;  width: 100%;    bottom:0;    left: 0; background:#ddd; color:#000;} 
.cat-custom-img .level-1{ width: 70%;}
.cat-custom-img img{ width: 20%;float: right; margin-top: -71px;}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<div class="" style="margin:25px 0; width:100%; float:left; clear:both">
    <?php
    $parentCatId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId(); 
    $root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCatId);
    $subCat = explode(',',$root->getChildren()); 

    $collection  = $root
                 ->getCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                 ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in", $subCat) );
    ?>
    <div class="accord-outer">
        <?php foreach($collection as $catname){  ?>
        <div class="accord-section">
            <div class="accord">
                <ul>
                    <?php $qty = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catname->getId())->getProductCount();?>
                    <li class="selected parent">                        
                        <a href="<?php echo $catname->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $catname->getName(); ?></a>
                       <?php if($catname['sliderimage']) {  ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$catname['sliderimage']; ?>" alt= "" >
                       <?php } ?>

                    </li>

                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catname->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0){ ?>                               
                        <?php $limit=1; ?>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory){ ?>
                                <li class="parent">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_subcategory->getUrl(); ?>">
                                        <?php echo $_subcategory->getName(); ?>
                                    </a>

                                    <?php $_subcategory1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                                    <?php $_subsubcategories1 = $_subcategory1->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                    <?php if (count($_subsubcategories1) > 0){ ?>   
                                        <ul class="">
                                             <?php foreach($_subsubcategories1 as $_subsubcategory){ ?>
                                             <li class="">
                                                <a href="<?php echo $_subsubcategory->getUrl(); ?>" >
                                                    <?php echo $_subsubcategory->getName(); ?>
                                                </a>
                                                <?php $_subcategory2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subsubcategory->getId()) ?>
                                                <?php $_subsubcategories2 = $_subcategory2->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                                <?php if (count($_subsubcategories2) > 0){ ?>   
                                                    <ul class="">
                                                         <?php foreach($_subsubcategories2 as $_subsubcategory2){ ?>
                                                         <li class="">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo $_subsubcategory2->getUrl(); ?>" >
                                                                <?php echo $_subsubcategory2->getName(); ?>
                                                            </a>
                                                         </li>
                                                        <?php }  ?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                             </li>
                                            <?php }  ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </li>
                                <?php $limit++; ?>

                         <?php } ?>                         
                    <?php } ?>
                   <li class="parent load"><span class="loadmore">Load More</span><span class="loadless">Load Less</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery('.accord').navAccordion({

    // Text inside of expand button
    expandButtonText : "+", 

    // Text inside of collapse button
    collapseButtonText: "-",  

    // Expand the selected channel
    selectedExpand: "true",   

    // Class that will be used to detect the currently selected channel
    // This will check the "parentElement" for this class (the parent <li> by default)
    selectedClass: "selected",  

    // Apply accordion to all levels
    // Setting this to false will apply the accordion only to the first level
    multipleLevels: "true",  

    // Width of accordion expand/collapse button as a percentage or pixels
    buttonWidth: "20%",  

    // Position of button
    buttonPosition: "right",  

    // Speed of slide animation
    // "fast", "slow", or number in milliseconds such as 500
    slideSpeed: "fast",   

    // Parent element type, class or ID
    // You don't need to change this if you're using a ul > li > ul pattern
    parentElement: "li",  

    // Child element type, class or ID 
    // You don't need to change this if you're using a ul > li > ul pattern
    childElement: "ul",   

    // Setting to true will make any link with sub-nav behave as if it were set to header only, making the link inaccessible
    // This option is useful if you are using the plugin for a non-navigation area 
    headersOnly: false,  

    // Setting to true to apply the accordion only to links that are set as "header only" (have no href)
    headersOnlyCheck: false,

    // Delay following the href of links until after the accordion the has expanded
    delayLink: false,  

    // Time in milliseconds to delay before following href - will use "slideSpeed" by default if nothing else is set 
    delayAmount: null 
    });

    function accord(ac){
        //console.log(ac);
        var total = jQuery(ac).find('ul li.parent').length; 
        //console.log(total);
        if(total > 5){          
            jQuery(ac).find('ul li.parent').each(function(i) {
                if(i==1){
                    jQuery( this ).toggleClass( "visible" );
                }
                else if(i<=3){
                    jQuery( this ).toggleClass( "visible" );
                }
                else if(i == (total-1)){
                    jQuery( this ).addClass( "button" );
                }
                else{
                    jQuery( this ).toggleClass( "hidden" );
                }                       
            });
        }
        else{
            jQuery(ac).find('ul li.parent.load').hide();
            //alert('afsdfdf');
        }
    }

    jQuery('.accord-outer .accord-section').each(function(){                    
        accord(jQuery(this).children('.accord'));                   
    })
    jQuery('.load').click(function(event){  
        accord(jQuery(this).closest('.accord'));    
        jQuery(this).find('.loadless').removeClass("accordion-active");
        jQuery(this).find('.loadless').toggleClass("active");
        jQuery(this).find('.loadmore').toggleClass("active");   
    });
    jQuery(".loadless").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.accord').find('li.parent.active ul').css('display', 'none');
        jQuery(this).closest('.accord').find('li.parent.active .accordion-collapsed').css('display', 'inline-block');
        jQuery(this).closest('.accord').find('li.parent.active .accordion-expanded').css('display', 'none');

    }); 
});
</script>

<style>
    .accord-outer{width:100%; float:left;}
    .accord{width:25%; float:left; margin:0 0 20px;}
    .visible{display:block;}
    .hidden{display:none;}
    .loadmore{display:inline-block;}
    .loadless{display:none;}
    .loadmore.active{display:none;}
    .loadless.active{display:inline-block;}
    .accord { background: #46CFB0; width: 25%;}

    /* First Level */

    .accord ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #1ABC9C; }
    .accord ul li { border-top: 1px solid #1ABC9C; }
    .accord ul li a { color: #FFFFFF; display: block; font-size: 1.1em; line-height: normal; padding: 12px 20px; text-decoration: none; }
    .accord ul li a:hover { background: #E95546; text-decoration: none; 

    /* Second Level */

    .accord ul ul { border-bottom: none }
    .accord ul ul li { border-top: 1px solid #46CFB0; background: #34BC9D; }
    .accord ul ul li a { color: #FFFFFF; display: block; font-size: 1em; line-height: normal; padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 2.5em; }
    .accord ul ul li a:hover { background: #E95546; }

    /* Third Level */

    .accord ul ul ul { border-top: 1px solid #46CFB0; }
    .accord ul ul ul li { border: none; }
    .accord ul ul ul li a {  padding-left: 3.5em; padding-top: 0.25em; padding-bottom: 0.25em; }

    /* Accordion Button */

    ul li.has-subnav .accordion-btn { color: #fff; background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.15);  font-size: 16px; }
</style>
```